# force the date to be saved in a csv file in a specified format

Tags: python-3.x, csv

All,

I have a script that runs and when it does it saves the dates in a csv file by appending the file every time it runs.

The code shown below

```
with open('historyWeekly.csv','a',newline='') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([todayScript])
```

the name of the csv file is 'historyWeekly.csv' and the format of todayScript is '06-05-2018'

The date is saved succesfully. However when I open the csv file I do find that the format has changed to 06/05/2018.

Using python, how can I force the format to stay the same?
or how can I read the csv with the correct format ('06-05-2018' instead of 06/05/2018)

Many  Thanks

Comment: How are you opening the csv file? If in Excel, do you see the same result in Notepad or other text editor?

Comment: I am opening the csv file in excel. When i read the csv file using python, python read the dates with the format 06/05/2018.  When opening the csv file with notepad I see the format 06/05/2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proposed solution to my question is to read the csv in python and convert the data back to the desired format.

```
pd.read_csv("path/historyWeekly.csv")
```

initial data:

```
        Dates
0  06/05/2018

history['Dates']=pd.to_datetime(history['Dates'], format="%m/%d/%Y")
history['Dates']=history['Dates'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')


        Dates
0  06-05-2018
```